# DNN 7 - User creation notification and random password not working

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I am using DNN 07.03.04 (45) and I have problem when creating a new user. When notification and random password box is marked (see image) user receives no notification and no random password on given email. Is this a bug?  [image]

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a bug. I believe they stopped sending password as plain text strings in an Email since version 7.x (maybe even earlier) for security reasons. That is why you can only reset your password with a token you receive by mail. Before that DNN would send you your password by mail if you had forgotten it (see DNN 6 screenshot for proof).

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The problem, I didn't got notification to email that I provided during registration. Did they stop send notification to the email  as well?

Comment: No, emails are still being send.

Comment: Another problem is if you, as the administrator, creates the user account which sends off the New User Registration email, how does the user obtain a password if it's not included in the email?

Comment: I've added the password reset token to the new user registration email, which works, just wondering if this is the best choice.